# C : Modulus operator on unsigned int gives unexpected output

Tags: c, unsigned, modulus, unsigned-integer

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    unsigned a = -20;
    unsigned b = 10;
    printf("%d\n", (a % b));
    printf("%d\n", (-20 % 10));
}

Output:
6
0
```

The second printf prints the expected value of 0 while the first printf prints 6.
Why this unexpected output with unsigned ints?

Comment: Because `1<<32` is not divisable by 10 ? BTW: *Why* do you use a negative initialiser for an unsigned int? BTW2: printf() has the `%u` specifier for unsigned ints. `%d` is for signed ints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unsigned int` can hold values from 0 to `UINT_MAX`, no negative values. So `-20` is converted to `-20 + UINT_MAX + 1`.

On your system:

```
(-20 + UINT_MAX + 1) % 10 != -20 % 10
```

Answer (score 2):

And what are you expecting?

`a % b` is equivalent to, let's substitute the values and apply the unary `-` to the unsigned int value of 20, `(UINT_MAX-20+1) % 10` and the type of the result is `unsigned int` and you're printing it with `%d`, which is wrong. You should use `%u` here.